# metodo contarFijos en java

Tags: java, poo

necesito que el método contarFijos aumente el contador si el TIPO del telefono es "convencional" y el estado es "C".

el metodo contarFijos se debe crear en la clase Directorio y consiste en contar los telefonos que sean convencionales y que el estado sea "C".
A CONTINUCACION SE ENCUENTRA LA CLASE Directorio

```
            package com.cmc.evaluacion;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        
        
        public class Contacto {
            private String cedula;
            private String nombre;
            private String apellido;
            private Direccion direccion;
            static ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;
            
            public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
                this.cedula = cedula;
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.apellido = apellido;
                telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
            }
        
            static ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
                return telefonos;
            }
        
            public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
                this.telefonos = telefonos;
            }
        
            public String getCedula() {
                return cedula;
            }
        
            public void setCedula(String cedula) {
                this.cedula = cedula;
            }
        
            public String getNombre() {
                return nombre;
            }
        
            public void setNombre(String nombre) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
            }
        
            public String getApellido() {
                return apellido;
            }
        
            public void setApellido(String apellido) {
                this.apellido = apellido;
            }
        
            public Direccion getDireccion() {
                return direccion;
            }
        
            public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
                this.direccion = direccion;
            }
            
            public void imprimir(){
                System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
                System.out.println("Direccion: "+this.direccion.getCallePrincipal()+" y "+this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
                
            }
            
            public void imprimir2(){
                if (this.direccion!=null) {
                    System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
                    System.out.println("Direccion: "+this.direccion.getCallePrincipal()+" y "+this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
                    
                } else {
                    System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
                    System.out.println("No tiene asociada una direccion");
                }
                
            }
            
            public void agregarTelefono(Telefono tel){
                telefonos.add(tel);
                
            }
            
            public void mostrarTelefonos(){
                Telefono tem=null;
                for (int i=0;i<telefonos.size();i++) {
                    tem=telefonos.get(i);
                    if (tem.getEstado().equals("C")) {
                        System.out.println(tem.getTipo()+"-"+tem.getNombre());
                    }
                }
            }
            
            public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos(){
                Telefono tem=null;
                ArrayList<Telefono> tel = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
                for (int i = 0; i <telefonos.size(); i++) {
                    tem=telefonos.get(i);
                    if (tem.getEstado().equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
                        tel.add(tem);
                    }
                }
                return tel;
            }
            
            
            
        }
```

existe una clase Contacto la cual agrego a continuacion donde se puede ver los detalles.

```
package com.cmc.evaluacion;

      import java.util.ArrayList;


      public class Contacto {
      private String cedula;
      private String nombre;
      private String apellido;
      private Direccion direccion;
      static ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;

    public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
   }

   static ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
       return telefonos;
   }

   public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
      this.telefonos = telefonos;
   }

  public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
   }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
    }

      public void setNombre(String nombre) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      }

      public String getApellido() {
     return apellido;
    }

      public void setApellido(String apellido) {
       this.apellido = apellido;
       }

      public Direccion getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
       }

      public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
      }

      public void imprimir(){
          System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
            System.out.println("Direccion: 
    "+this.direccion.getCallePrincipal()+" y 
    "+this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
    
    }

       public void imprimir2(){
         if (this.direccion!=null) {
        System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
        System.out.println("Direccion: 
       "+this.direccion.getCallePrincipal()+" y 
      "+this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
        
        } else {
            System.out.println("***"+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+"***");
            System.out.println("No tiene asociada una direccion");
        }
    
     }

    public void agregarTelefono(Telefono tel){
        telefonos.add(tel);
    
     }

      public void mostrarTelefonos(){
        Telefono tem=null;
        for (int i=0;i<telefonos.size();i++) {
        tem=telefonos.get(i);
        if (tem.getEstado().equals("C")) {
            System.out.println(tem.getTipo()+"-"+tem.getNombre());
        }
     }
     }

       public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos(){
            Telefono tem=null;
            ArrayList<Telefono> tel = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
            for (int i = 0; i <telefonos.size(); i++) {
            tem=telefonos.get(i);
            if (tem.getEstado().equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
            tel.add(tem);
            }
        }
         return tel;
      }



  }
```

la duda es en como llamo al estado y al tipo del telefono para hacer la condición?
la que quiero saber es cual es la manera correcta para llamar al tipo y estado del telefono sin que genere un nullpointerexception

```
public int contarFijos(){
            int count = 0;
            Contacto tem=null;
            for (int i = 0; i <contactos.size(); i++) {
                tem=contactos.get(i);
                if (tem.getTelefonos()!=null) {
                    count=count+1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: Recomiendo que por favor expongas las clases que estas usando ya que no podemos adivinar como está tu código, nos será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @Omar  ya agregue las clases, agradeceria mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola LuisCar, podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Comment: @Omar gracias por tu aporte amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int ContarFijos()
{
   int cont = 0;
   Contacto tmp;
   Telefono tel;

   for(int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++)
   {
      tmp = contactos.get(i);

      for(int j = 0; j < tmp.getTelefonos().size(); j++)
      {
         tel = tmp.getTelefonos().get(j);

         if(tel.getEstado() == "C" && tel.getTipo() == "convencional")
         {
            cont++;
         }
      }
   }

   return cont;
}
```

Primero se hace un **ciclo for** que recorra todos los contactos y como cada contacto tiene a su vez una lista de teléfonos pues se hace otro **ciclo for** que recorra los teléfonos de cada contacto. Por cada teléfono se pregunta si es del tipo que deseas y del estado que deseas, de cumplirse esta condición se incrementa la **variable cont**. Posteriormente se retorna **cont** indicando la cantidad de teléfonos que cumplen con la condición.